# How to map Excel internal xml to worksheet cells in a template file

Tags: excel, xml

I'm struggling with xml mapping in Excel using Excel embedded xml files as source files. From my web searches it seems to be a bit of a special case, as I don't get to be to many hits on this, or I'm not able to formulate my search correctly.

I've generated a Excel file that is store as a template file in a PLM system. When a user create a new object in this system an Excel file is created from this template, and a custom xml file is included in this Excel with metadata from the PLM system.

In the originally created template Excel the data in the Excel embedded xml file is mapped to certain cells in one of the Excel sheets. When the system generates a new Excel file, based on this template, the xml file the values for the different parameters are updated, the mapped fields are there, however the updated values in the xml mapping is not connected/transferred to the mapping in the cells. Only the original values in the template file is shown within the worksheet. The values in the xml mapping however is confirmed to be updated.

If you redo the mapping it works, and the xml data will "flow" into the sheet cells when changes are done in the PLM system and xml data is synced to the Excel file. If you then use this as your new template you get back to the original issue again with the link between the mapping and the cells in the Excel sheet being broken.

All mapping fields created by the system keeps their names in every version of the files so there should be no inconsistencies here.

Any input is appreciated.

Thanks
Fnk